# Dollars in Makefile environment variables

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, environment-variables

Is it possible to "disable" variable expansion in my `Makefile` for a certain section?

Here's an example of the issue I'm having:

```makefile
print_command:
    @echo '$(COMMAND)'
```

And here's the output I'm getting:

```shell
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $SHELL'
$ make print_command
My favourite shell is HELL
$ make print_command COMMAND='Welcome to $SHELL'
Welcome to HELL
```

And what I would like to get:

```shell
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $SHELL'
$ make print_command
My favourite shell is $SHELL
$ make print_command COMMAND='Welcome to $SHELL'
Welcome to $SHELL
```

Is it possible to do this without using a double dollar like so:

```shell
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $$SHELL'
$ make print_command
My favourite shell is $SHELL
$ make print_command COMMAND='Welcome to $$SHELL'
Welcome to $SHELL
```

In it's simplest form I'm looking to forward the exact contents of the variable `COMMAND` without `make` mangling it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `$$` double-dollar and double-quote it.

```
print_command:
                @echo "$$COMMAND"
```

Like,

```
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $SHELL'; make print_command
My favourite shell is $SHELL
```

Check out this [`How to Use Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-How-to-Use-Variables) page from the `GNU` make page.

If you just add a single-quote, `make` literally prints out the variable:-
e.g. with

```
print_command:
                @echo '$$COMMAND'
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $SHELL'; make print_command
$COMMAND
```

Because `$` carries a special meaning in Makefile and that needs to be escaped. If you need `make` to expand the value for the variable defined, use a `value` syntax as

```
print_command:
                @echo $(value COMMAND)
$ export COMMAND='My favourite shell is $SHELL'; make print_command
My favourite shell is /bin/bash
```

In the above case, the value of environment variables being expanded to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Is it possible to pass it on the command line without `export` (i.e. after `make` but still without a double dollar? I'd assume it's not, as it's the equivalent of having the definition in the `Makefile` itself.