# Uppercasing variable in a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm using a makefile to deploy static content to an s3 bucket using Amazon's CLI. I want to throw in a variable to choose the target destination so I don't need to repeat the same script in different make verbs.

I seem to have got it to work but I want to make the argument case-insensitive from the terminal when it's executed. Here's what I have:

```
S3_NAME_DEV = com-mydomain-application-dev
S3_NAME_LIVE = com-mydomain-application
deploy:
    # e.g. make deploy t=LIVE
    aws s3 sync dist/ s3://$(S3_NAME_${t})
```

I tried adding the two carets (which is supported in bash 4 and I'm using) `$(S3_NAME_${t^^})` but doesn't work :/. Here's the output when I do `$ make deploy t=live` (variable just disappears).

```
$ make deploy t=live
# e.g. make deploy t=LIVE
aws s3 sync dist/ s3://
```

I thought it might be useful to include what the aws command might look like (so that not knowing the AWS CLI doesn't throw you off).

```
aws s3 sync dist/ s3://com-mydomain-application
```

In the shell I call the `make` from I can do this successfully:

```
$ t=live
$ echo ${t^^}
LIVE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bonus points: setting default value

## UPDATE:

So make doesn't inherit the bash which executes it like I assumed. If I `@echo "my version is: $$BASH_VERSION"` in the make file I get version 3.2 (OS X default). Pretty good chance fixing this will solve the issue.

Comment: @Sundeep Sorry I didn't include that; I've edited the post.

Comment: no probs, does it work if you give all caps?

Comment: @Sundeep once I include the `^^` is will give the empty value with either `t=live` or `t=LIVE`. If I remove `^^` `$ make deploy t=LIVE` will work again.

Comment: okay, can you try `$(S3_NAME_"${t^^}")` ?

Comment: @Sundeep gave it a shot. Same output unfortunately.

Comment: apparently, you might need to [double the $ for variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769390/dollars-in-makefile-environment-variables).. so try `$(S3_NAME_"$${t^^}")`

Comment: That didn't work either :/ though I think you're on the right tracks

Comment: hmm, no more ideas.. hope someone else will help you :)

Comment: @Sundeep thanks anyway :)

Comment: Makefile uses `/bin/sh` by default. That just happens to be `/bin/bash` version 3.2 on your machine. Honestly, you are going to put far more work into trying to make your script "user-friendly" than anyone will ever spend just typing `LIVE`/`DEV` instead of `live`/`dev`.

Comment: Or rather, no one is likely to *want* to type `LIVE` instead of `live` from the command line, so just use the lowercase string in your Makefile variable (`S3_NAME_dev` and `S3_NAME_live`).

Comment: @chepner A fair point but I do want to do more complex things with these makefiles so this is only going to help me understand what's going on. Even though this particular use case is not very compelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried adding the two carets (which is supported in bash 4 and I'm using) `$(S3_NAME_${t^^})` but doesn't work.

This is because `$(S3_NAME_...)` part is being expanded by make, whereas you expect the `${t^^}` part to be expanded by `bash`, but `bash` is not involved when `make` expands variables.

Convert `t` to uppercase early in your makefile:

```
override t := $(shell X="${t}"; echo $${X^^})
```

Without `override` it will need a new variable name:

```
u := $(shell X="${t}"; echo $${X^^})
# use ${u} instead of ${t}
```

Comment: This works, though the make script doesn't appear to have context of it's previously executed lines so I have to do it all inline i.e. `aws s3 sync dist/ s3://S3_NAME_$(shell X="${t}"; echo $${X^^})`. Am I right that that's the case

Comment: @freebie _the make script doesn't appear to have context of it's previously executed lines_ - that should not be the case. If you invoke other makefiles make sure you `export` the variable, e.g. `export u := ...` and use `${u}` instead of `${t}`.

Comment: I did try putting export in front of the variable assignment but it didn't seem to work. Sorry on my phone so I dont have the error at hand. This answer is correct though and has solved my problem. I guess the scoping of the make variables is a different issue. Thanks