# in a Makefile obtain the Current UID

Tags: docker, makefile

I'm trying to update my makefile instruction, but I don't understand how to do it.

I want to execute this docker instruction:

```
start: ## Start the environment
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

with this prefix:

```
CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g)
```

like this:

```
start: ## Start the environment
CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose stop
CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

If I add direct that string and I try to run the makefile in the console appear this:

```
CURRENT_UID=: docker-compose stop
CURRENT_UID=: docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
```

The `$()` did not work, so the result is just `:`
What do I need to do?

I tried to follow this example but it doesn't work
[Dollars in Makefile environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769390/dollars-in-makefile-environment-variables)

Comment: It would make more sense to compute the string once and `export` it.

Comment: how? i tried to follow this but I cant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769390/dollars-in-makefile-environment-variables

Comment: That seems like a different use case. In the Makefile itself, `CURRENT_UID := $(shell id -u):$(shell id -g)` and then `export `CURRENT_UID` (though tangentially, probably [avoid upper case for your private variables.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)